# как исправить ошибку check() missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

root.resizable(width = False, height = False )
root.geometry( '300x200' )
root.title( 'Вход в систему' )

root[ 'bg' ] = '#808080'

def check( event, root ):
    L = login.get()
    P = password.get()

    if L and P:
        messagbox.showinfo('Success', 'Вы успешно вошли!')
    if not L and P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x1', 'Введите логин')
    elif not P and L:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x2', 'Введите пароль')
    if not L and not P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 1x2', 'Серьезно -_-')

text_login = Label( text = 'Login', font = 'Consolas 20', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080', )
login = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center' )

text_pass = Label(text = 'Password', font = 'Comfortaa 20' , fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080')

password = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center', show = '*' )

check_status = Checkbutton(text = 'Остатся в системе!!', font = 'Comfortaa 13', bg = '#808080', fg = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF')

enter = Button(text = 'Войти', font = 'Consolas 13', bg = '#C0C0C0', fg = '#FFFFFF', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', width = '10', command = check )



#packet
text_login.pack()
login.pack()
text_pass.pack()
password.pack()

enter.pack()
```

Comment: Разумеется, надо эти два аргумента добавить в вызов `check()`. Так как вы кусок кода привели без строки, в которой ошибка:-)), то больше сложно что-то посоветовать.

Comment: А если убрать аргументы из определения функции: `def check():`? Они там вроде не нужны.

Comment: @Сергей Она там как коллбэк используется, аргументы если бы и передавались, то автоматически )  `command = check`

Answer (score 0):

ваша ошибка в этой строчке 
`enter = Button(text = 'Войти', font = 'Consolas 13', bg = '#C0C0C0', fg = '#FFFFFF', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', width = '10', command = check )`
Если перевести ошибку, то получится примерно так "функция check требует 2 параметра"
Из этого следует что, вам нужно заполнить функцию двумя параметрами.
Я не понимаю зачем вам эти параметры (они здесь лишние) поэтому
2 способ:
Но если вам не нужны эти параметры!

```
def check(): <= сюда не пихать параметры
    L = login.get()
    P = password.get()

    if L and P:
        messagbox.showinfo('Success', 'Вы успешно вошли!')
    if not L and P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x1', 'Введите логин')
    elif not P and L:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x2', 'Введите пароль')
    if not L and not P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 1x2', 'Серьезно -_-')

text_login = Label( text = 'Login', font = 'Consolas 20', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080', )
login = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center' )

text_pass = Label(text = 'Password', font = 'Comfortaa 20' , fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080')

password = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center', show = '*' )

check_status = Checkbutton(text = 'Остатся в системе!!', font = 'Comfortaa 13', bg = '#808080', fg = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF')

enter = Button(text = 'Войти', font = 'Consolas 13', bg = '#C0C0C0', fg = '#FFFFFF', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', width = '10', command = check )
```

Вам необязателен параметр event

Я б хотел поправить код вот так:(ниже обяснение)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

root.resizable(False,False)
root.geometry( '300x200' )
root.title( 'Вход в систему' )

root[ 'bg' ] = '#808080'

def check():
    L = login.get()
    P = password.get()

    if L and P:
        messagbox.showinfo('Success', 'Вы успешно вошли!')
    if not L and P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x1', 'Введите логин')
    elif not P and L:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 0x2', 'Введите пароль')
    if not L and not P:
        messagbox.showerror('Error 1x2', 'Серьезно -_-')

def initializing():

    text_login = Label( text = 'Login', font = 'Consolas 20', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080', )
    login = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center' )
    text_login.pack()
    login.pack()

    text_pass = Label(text = 'Password', font = 'Comfortaa 20' , fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#808080')
    text_pass.pack()

    password = Entry( root, font = 'Consolas', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg = '#C0C0C0', relief = 'solid', justify = 'center', show = '*' )
    password.pack()

    check_status = Checkbutton(text = 'Остатся в системе!!', font = 'Comfortaa 13', bg = '#808080', fg = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF')
    check_status.pack()

    enter = Button(text = 'Войти', font = 'Consolas 13', bg = '#C0C0C0', fg = '#FFFFFF', activeforeground = '#FFFFFF', activebackground = '#808080', width = '10', command = check() )
    enter.pack()

initializing()
root.mainloop()
```

Код выглядит более компактнее, я переписал упаковщики, поставив их вместе с созданными объектами, и добавив скобки к `command = check()`. Поверь, так лучше читается, я работал на python более 1,6 года. Удачи!